# Deploy webapi controllers in different Azure App Services

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, azure-appservice

I need to investigate if this is possible or not.
The scenario is that we have an api (.net core 6.0) where we will have two controllers
**WeatherForecastController** and **HomeController**.
Now the question is, if it would possible to deploy each controller inside two different Azure App Services or two different App Service instances?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, to answer you, this need of yours is currently unattainable.**

#### WHY

*1. From the perspective of the project's release file*

In .net6 project, when we build the project, and it will generate `.dll` file which contains all the files(Controllers and Views and so on).

[image]

*2. Analyze from the publishing process.*

Simply put, after compiling the project file, it is finally uploaded to the wwwroot folder of the kudu site.

So the current requirements, from the perspective of the app service, cannot interfere with any behavior of the controllers in the project.